# Debug Specific Pass in GCC with GDB

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gdb

How to debug a specific pass in GCC (cc1) with gdb ?

I want to debug the "isolate paths" pass in gcc. I have a gcc toolchain built options with "-O0 -g3".

Where should I put breakpoints? If its a name of function where should we look for names ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of gcc you are debugging.  In the latest version, a pass is a subclass of some base class and you can put a breakpoint on the particular virtual method.  In older versions it was similar but there was, IIRC, a function pointer rather than a real method.  I suggest searching for "isolate paths" and then reading that file.